# Error on my procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

Everything is perfect in my eyes for real. Why It keep to say that Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors?. Can anybody know what are problems please?
[image]

Comment: put your code as text, not image

Comment: do basic debugging. add one line at time to found what line give you problem. But I tell you if you expect one user with more than one account `SELECT INTO` will fail

Comment: `users. password` with space between `.` and `password` looks questionable to me. Ditto `users. user_id %type`. To understand more about the errors you might try `SELECT * FROM ALL_ERRORS WHERE NAME='LOGIN_USE'`. Best of luck.

Comment: If you are compiling the procedure in SQL*Plus then either type `show errors` immediately after compilation (when you see the 'created with compilation errors' message), or else `show errors procedure login_use`. If you are using a tool such as SQL Developer or PL/SQL Developer, find out how to get it to show compilation errors automatically. You should not have to guess them.

Answer (score 0):

The "set serveroutput on" doesn't work with a stored procedure.

Never use a "select into" unless you certain know that the result is 1 record.
In your example the result can also be 2 (or more) records.

First make a cursor to count the records.
If the count results in 0 (zero) show the message. If the count results in 1 then use the "select into". Better the open, fetch, close construction. And if thesult of the count is more that 1 then show the message that there are more than 1 (!!!) acoounts.

Is this a work or a school related question?

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of OCR and manual fiddling, I make your procedure this:

```
create or replace procedure LOGIN_USE(USER_EMAIL IN VARCHAR, USER_PASSWORD IN
VARCHAR) IS

acttype users.account_type%type;
psword users. password%type;
acctuser users. user_id %type;
message varchar(100) := 'User name or password are incorrect';

Begin
SELECT account_type, password, user_id INTO acttype, psword, acctuser
FROM users
WHERE email = USER_EMAIL;

IF(psword = USER_PASSWORD) THEN
dbms_output.put_line('Hello, and Welcome ' || USER_EMAIL);
dbms_output.put_line('Account Type ' || acttype);
ELSIF (acctuser >= 2) THEN
dbms_output.put_line('Warning, You have more than two accounts');
ELSE
dbms_output.put_line(message);
END IF;
END;
```

When tidied up for readability (you should get into the habit of doing this yourself), I get this:

```
create or replace procedure login_use
    ( user_email    in varchar
    , user_password in varchar )
as
    acttype  users.account_type%type;
    psword   users.password%type;
    acctuser users.user_id%type;
    message  varchar(100) := 'User name or password are incorrect';

begin
    select account_type, password, user_id
    into   acttype,      psword,   acctuser
    from   users
    where  email = user_email;

    if psword = user_password then
        dbms_output.put_line('Hello, and Welcome ' || user_email);
        dbms_output.put_line('Account Type ' || acttype);
    elsif acctuser >= 2 then
        dbms_output.put_line('Warning, You have more than two accounts');
    else
        dbms_output.put_line(message);
    end if;
end;
```

This compiled fine for me after I created the `USERS` table as

```
create table users
( account_type  varchar2(10)
, password      varchar2(20)
, user_id       integer
, email         varchar2(50) );
```

However:

1. You should use `varchar2` not `varchar`.
2. I can't see the sense in selecting `users.user_id` into `acctuser` (confusing naming system btw) then checking whether that user ID is greater than 1 and if so warning that the user has more than two accounts. What are typical values for `user_id` in your `users` table? What does having an ID above 1 have to do with the number of accounts? Did you mean to count the rows? If `users.email` is not unique then you need to rethink the approach a bit.
3. I am very much hoping this is not for any real system, as it stores passwords in plain text. It would be something at least if you hashed them together with the email address.